# Deleting the first node in a linked list

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I am trying to delete the first node in my linked list and I'm not sure how to go about it. My linked list looks like this

```
typedef struct availableForRent{
   int milage;
   char plateNum[8];
   struct availableForRent * next;
} availablreForRent;
```

The initial node of my linked list is hard coded exactly like this

```
struct availableForRent * head = NULL;
head = malloc(sizeof(struct availableForRent));
head->milage = 190000;
fillString(head->plateNum);
head->next = NULL;
```

fillString just gets a user input and places it in an array

I add a member to my list through a push function like this

```
void pushAvailable(struct availableForRent * head) {
   struct availableForRent * current = head;
   while (current->next != NULL) {
      current = current->next;
   }

   current->next = malloc(sizeof(struct availableForRent));
   printf("Enter a milage amount: ");
   scanf("%d", &current->next->milage);
   fillString(current->next->plateNum);
   current->next->next = NULL;
}
```

and my function to remove the first member looks like this

```
struct availableForRent * next_node = *head;

if (next_node->next == NULL) {
   printf("Cannot remove member as it is the only data in the list!\n");
   return;
}

next_node = next_node->next;
free(*head);
*head = next_node;
```

When I run my program I get this error message,

```
rentalQ1(2799,0x7fff9d09b380) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee8f62a08: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

Does this mean that the node I am trying to free doesn't exist or something else?

Comment: Did you ever `malloc()` memory for the nodes in your linkedlist?

Comment: @Karl yes I malloc when I create each node in a separate function

Comment: It would probably be good to show how you did that in your question just in case that was done incorrectly. Since how you `malloc()` is related to how you `free()` the memory.

Comment: I'd edit your question and show more of your code, particularly how you added the nodes. At first glance, the snippet you posted seems like an okay "remove first node" but post the whole function. And, the root cause of the issue may be elsewhere and just manifests during removal.

Comment: I'd like to see how "head" is initialized and used in the calls?

Comment: Head is hard coded as show above, hopefully that helps

Comment: In the remove (pop) code, why are you using "*head" everywhere?  Unless this is a parameter to this as a function with the header not shown, I think just "head" is correct.  I'd expect your compiler warnings to have caught that though.

Comment: Since the function is called with a double pointer calling *head would refer to the actual values within head not just the pointer to head. If I understand double pointers correctly

Comment: I also get the same error message when I try run my cleaner function that just frees all the nodes in the list. If that also gives and hints

Answer (score 0):

It appears that not mallocing the next_node was my problem.

```
next_node = malloc(sizeof(struct availableForRent));
```

Comment: Careful.  Just because a problem goes away. doesn't mean it is fixed.  Hard to say from the code you've shared, but this doesn't feel like the fix.  Personally, I'd look at your handling of the head pointer.

Comment: Yeah your right, when you say look at the handling could you be more specific? Im no sure what you mean by that